# Broken images marker on leaflet map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Good afternoon everyone, I think a screenshot will tell better than words:
[I would like a real marker instead of what is actually printed...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAwAR.png)

Here is the corresponding server.R part of the code (where fixed_points is a nrow(fixed_points) x 2 matrix with lat/lon coordinates

```
library(shiny); library(rCharts); library(leaflet)
output$baseMap  <- renderMap({
  baseMap <- Leaflet$new()
  baseMap$setView(c(lng = 2.812500, lat = 46.732331), zoom = 6)
  baseMap$tileLayer(provider = "Stamen.TonerLite")
  for (i in 1:nrow(fixed_points)) {baseMap$marker(c(fixed_points[i, "lat"], fixed_points[i, "lon"]))}
  baseMap$fullScreen(TRUE)
  baseMap
})
```

and the ui.R

```
showOutput("baseMap", "leaflet") // or chartOuput(...), it works the same
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the question? Would you like to display a marker at the location instead of the broken image?

Comment: That's it. Sorry, I modified my post to make it clearer

Comment: Your code does not seem to be reproducible. For example, running it in Rstudio returns: `Error in output$baseMap <- renderMap({ : object 'output' not found`

Comment: I figured something: in fact my shiny app displays on one navbar page the renderMap({}) shown above and on the other a renderLeaflet({}). If I comment what generates the leaflet in my code, the markers are fine. If I run all together, the markers are broken. It would mean the different kinds of maps are "blocking" each other? I don't know if you've encountered this before... (bonne chance pour ton doctorat en tout cas ;) )